# TLS 1.3 support for .Net 4.0

Tags: .net, security, ssl

I have an application compiled to in .Net 4.0(require this to support backward compatibility) and it does support TLS 1.2 when we install a higher .Net version(4.5.2) on the workstation.
Does this scenario remains the same to support TLS 1.3 installing .Net 4.8 runtime on the workstation without compiling an application to .Net 4.8 and just target the .Net 4.8 runtime in our application?

Comment: Microsoft in general does not yet support TLS 1.3 in .NET Framework, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/microsoft-tls-1-3-support-reference/ What's going to happen in the future is still to be observed.

Comment: Microsoft suggests leaving SecurityProtocol as SystemDefault. SystemDefault = "Allows the operating system to choose the best protocol to use, and to block protocols that are not secure. Unless your app has a specific reason not to, you should use this value." This leaves me to believe it would automatically switch to TLS 1.3 when supported and available. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol